# How to use computed value in relation in typeorm/nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Here is my Entity:

```js
@Column({ nullable: false })
cover_photo: string;

get cover_photo_link(): string {
  return `http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/uploads/destinations/${this.cover_photo}`;
}
```

How can I use cover_photo_link in the below code?

```js
const data = await dataRepository.find({
  relations: {
    destination: true,
  },
  select: {
    destination: {
      id: true,
      name: true,
      cover_photo: true,
      cover_photo_link: true,
    },
  },
});
```

Here I am getting the following error:

```
Property "cover_photo_link" was not found in "Entity". Make sure your query is correct.
```

How can I call `cover_photo_link` in my above query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Listeners](https://typeorm.io/listeners-and-subscribers) for that case. There is no need to `select` cover_photo_link as it is not a `@Column`.

I've used only `@AfterLoad`, `@AfterInsert` and `@AfterUpdate`. You might need some more.

```js
@Entity()
export class Photo {
    @Column({ type: "varchar", nullable: false })
    cover_photo: string;

    cover_photo_link: string;

    @AfterLoad()
    @AfterInsert()
    @AfterUpdate()
    updateCoverPhotoLink() {
        this.cover_photo_link = `http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/uploads/destinations/${this.cover_photo}`;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you don't need to `select` this property all the time, `@VirtualColumn` might be a decision.

```js
@VirtualColumn({
    type: "varchar",
    query: (alias) =>
        `SELECT "http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/uploads/destinations/" || ${alias}.cover_photo`,
})
cover_photo_link: string;
```

Comment: But listener will load at each instance i.e. at each times the entity is loaded. Some times I may not need cover_photo_link.

Comment: Virtual column is not a default feature in typeorm.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9339) is the pr. It is merged on September 22. You can read comments in 'Files changed'. It is done for just for your case.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use QueryBuilder:

```
const data = await dataRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('data')
  .select([
    'destination.id',
    'destination.name',
    'destination.cover_photo',
    `CONCAT('http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/uploads/destinations/', destination.cover_photo) AS cover_photo_link`
  ])
  .leftJoin('data.destination', 'destination')
  .getRawMany();
```

Comment: Yes I can use querybuilder, I am looking for the way if I can do it by ORM